# dice rolling game: odd sum gets a malus, even sum a bonus

Tags: python, if-statement

I have to make a dice game. Down below is my code so far for the actual dice rolling section.

If the total number from the dices are even, 10 points must be added on. However if the total is an odd number, 5 points must be taken away.

```
  import random

  print("player 1, please roll dice")
  rolldice=input("would you like to roll dice?")
  if rolldice=="yes":
     roll1 = random.randint(1,6)

  roll2=random.randint(1,6)

  print("You rolled",roll1)
  print("you rolled",roll2)
  if roll1+roll2="2,4,6,8,10,12":
      print("roll1+roll2+10"):
```

Comment: You are treating integers like they are strings.  Integers should not be inside quotes unless you want them to be strings.

Comment: What do you expect this statement `roll1+roll2="2,4,6,8,10,12"` to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

print("player 1,please roll dies")
rolldice=input("would you like to roll dies?")
if rolldice=="yes":
    roll1 = random.randint(1,6)

    roll2=random.randint(1,6)

   print("You rolled",roll1)
   print("you rolled",roll2)
   res = roll1 + roll2
   if (roll1+roll2) % 2 == 0:
       res += 10
   else:
       res -= 5
   print(res):
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added comments in my code to explain the mistakes in your code and various methods to fix them

```
import random   #indentation must be fixed in your code
print("player 1,please roll dice")
rolldice=input("would you like to roll dice?")
if rolldice=="yes":
     roll1 = random.randint(1,6)
     roll2=random.randint(1,6)
     print("You rolled",roll1)
     print("you rolled",roll2)
     if roll1+roll2 %2==0:      #here % gives reminder of division,this is an
         print(roll1+roll2+10)       #easier method or it should be roll1+roll2 in [2,4,6,8,10,12] (the list shouldn't be in quotations, that would mean that it is a string,not a list)
     else:         # if it isn't an even no, it will obviously be odd, so using else
         print(roll1+roll2-5)
```

also: you've added `:` after a print statement in the last line, that is a syntax error: `:`   is used only when there is a block of text at a different indentation level. i.e., for `for`loops, `if`, `else`, `elif` etc

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

print("player 1, please roll dies")
rolldice = input("would you like to roll dies?")
if rolldice == "yes":
    roll1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    roll2 = random.randint(1, 6)

    print("You rolled", roll1)
    print("you rolled", roll2)
    if (roll1 + roll2) % 2 == 0:
        print(roll1 + roll2 + 10)
    else:
        print(roll1 + roll2 - 5)
```